# Зависает Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

После добавления `do while`, при нажатие на play, кнопка залипает и ничего не происходит, Unity никак не реагирует.

Программа отвечает(не пишет,что программа приостановила работу).При закрытии через диспетчер задач-закрывается моментально без ошибок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите код текстом, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А чего вы ожидаете?

`Vector3.forward.z` - это константа. Оно всегда `1` равно.

У вас игра во втором цикле намертво зависает, т.к. это значение никогда не меняется.

Comment: Есть ли возможность предотвратить,обнаружить такие казусы до запуска?

Comment: @Alexander возможно, если вы в VS работает, ReSharper такое показывает.